# ORA-00900: invalid SQL statement in SQL while oOdbcCommandProp.ExecuteNonQuery()

Tags: vb.net, odbc

while executing stored procedure I'm having this trouble

I'm trying to execute stored procedure which have some input parameter

```
  oOdbcCommandProp.CommandText = "{call PROCEDURE SP_SR_GENERATOR_12(?, ?, ?)"
            oOdbcCommandProp.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure

            oOdbcCommandProp.Parameters.Add("in_select", OdbcType.VarChar).Value = selectin
            oOdbcCommandProp.Parameters.Add("in_loop_gen_qty", OdbcType.Int).Value = Convert.ToInt32(loopgen)  
            oOdbcCommandProp.Parameters.Add("in_bau_no", OdbcType.Int).Value = Convert.ToInt32(bau_number)                
            oOdbcCommandProp.Parameters.Add("in_userName", OdbcType.VarChar).Value = LoginInfoVB.UserName
            oOdbcCommandProp.Parameters.Add("in_sach_no", OdbcType.VarChar).Value = sach_in
            oOdbcCommandProp.Parameters.Add("in_po_no", OdbcType.VarChar).Value = po_in
            oOdbcCommandProp.Parameters.Add("in_machine_sr_no", OdbcType.Int).Value = Convert.ToInt32(cmbMachine.SelectedValue.ToString())

 If oOdbcCommandProp.Connection.State = 0 Then
                oOdbcCommandProp.Connection.Open()
            End If

 oOdbcCommandProp.ExecuteNonQuery()
```

Comment: If you set the `CommandType` to `StoredProcedure` then the `CommandText` should just be the name of the sproc.

Comment: I got the one ,The no of question mark in bracket defines the no of input parameter we are passing to procedure. @jmcilhinney

Comment: That's true but that's still wrong in this context.  Do what I said.  If you set `CommandType` to `StoredProcedure` then set `CommandText` to just the procedure name, i.e. "SP_SR_GENERATOR_12".  Otherwise, you're not calling a stored procedure directly but rather you're executing inline SQL that calls the stored procedure.  If you're executing inline SQL then you should be setting `CommandType` to `Text`, which is the default.